# Node Express HTTPS ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: node.js, express, https, http-tunneling

I am running a Node/Express Server. I am able to successfully login and establish a secure connection (HTTPS) and have never had trouble connecting. However, I have two clients who are trying to log in to my server, but they cannot establish a connection. Their browser shows the following error when they try to connect:

[image]

I have done some research and pretty much concluded that the problem is on their end. I am in a little over my head here so I am looking for anyone who has some insight regarding how I can approach a solution.

I really have no idea where to start so I am open to any suggestions for diagnosing or resolving this.

If it is a VPN or proxy issue, do I need to somehow contact my clients' IT group or is there a workaround I can do on my end?

I have chosen not to include the source code for my Node server because I am not sure about the legal ramifications but I can include certain pieces if it is necessary to diagnose the issue. For what it's worth, it is a pretty vanilla Node/Express HTTPS server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your two clients who it's failing for, are they inside the same network?

Comment: No. They work for the same company but they are in different states. It is worth mentioning that I have not confirmed that the second user is actually getting the same tunneling error message. I am working on setting up a meeting to confirm this but for now I am working under the assumption that they are having the same problem.

Comment: So, what happens if they turn their VPN off?

Comment: They are not the sort of users who would know how to do that, which is part of the problem. I can walk them through that but I wanted to get some more information before I went back to them. I guess I am looking for a test that I can run with them that will definitively point me or their IT group towards a solution.

Comment: Hmm, yeh, that is a problem :/  Not really sure anyone on here will be able to help without additional details. I imagine that if they turn their VPN off, all will be well. But of course, that's a massive assumption. I have only ever seen this once... and they were connected over a VPN.

Comment: OK, that is still helpful.  Is the problem something like a TLS version/compatibility issue between their VPN and my server?

Comment: Sorry dude... I mean sure, it could be, but impossible to say. Good luck